# vector binding in R

Tags: r

I would like to implement a simulation program, which requires the following structure:

It has a for loop, the program will generate an vector in each iteration. I need each generated vector is appended to the existing vector.

I do not how how to do this in R. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These answers work, but they all require a call to a non-deterministic function like `sample()` in the loop. This is not loop-invariant code (it is random each time), but it can still be moved out of the `for` loop. The trick is to use the `n` argument and generate all the random numbers you need beforehand (if your problem allows this; some may not, but many do). Now you make *one* call rather than `n` calls, which matters if your `n` is large. Here is a quick example random walk (but many problems can be phrased this way). Also, full disclosure: I haven't had *any* coffee today, so please point out if you see an error :-)

```
steps <- 30
n <- 100
directions <- c(-1, 1)

results <- vector('list', n)

for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  walk <- numeric(steps)
  for (s in seq_len(steps)) {
    walk[s] <- sample(directions, 1)
  }
  results[[i]] <- sum(walk)
}
```

We can rewrite this with one call to `sample()`:

```
all.steps <- sample(directions, n*steps, replace=TRUE)
dim(all.steps) <- c(n, steps)
walks <- apply(all.steps, 1, sum)
```

Proof of speed increase (n=10000):

```
> system.time({
+ for (i in seq_len(n)) {
+   walk <- numeric(steps)
+   for (s in seq_len(steps)) {
+     walk[s] <- sample(directions, 1)
+   }
+   results[[i]] <- sum(walk)
+ }})
   user  system elapsed 
  4.231   0.332   4.758 

> system.time({
+ all.steps <- sample(directions, n*steps, replace=TRUE)
+ dim(all.steps) <- c(n, steps)
+ walks <- apply(all.steps, 1, sum)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.010   0.001   0.012
```

If your simulation needs just one random variable per simulation function call, use `sapply()`, or better yet the `multicore` package's `mclapply()`. Revolution Analytics's `foreach` package may be of use here too. Also, JD Long has a great presentation and post about simulating stuff in R on Hadoop via Amazon's EMR [here](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2010/02/you-can-hadoop-it-its-elastic-boogie-woogie-woog-ie/) (I can't find the video, but I'm sure someone will know).

Take home points:

- Preallocate with `numeric(n)` or `vector('list', n)`
- Push invariant code out of `for` loops. Cleverly push stochastic functions out of code with their `n` argument.
- Try hard for `sapply()` or `lapply()`, or better yet `mclapply`.
- Don't use `x <- c(x, rnorm(100))`. Every time you do this, a member of R-core kills a puppy.

Comment: Awesome answer, especially without having coffee!  I assume `all.walk` comes from the lack of coffee... ;-)

Comment: You could speed up more by using `rowSums(all.steps)` instead of `apply(all.steps, 1, sum)`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best thing you can do is preallocate a list of length n (n is number of iterations) and flatten out the list after you're done.

```
n <- 10
start <- vector("list", n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  a[[i]] <- sample(10)
}
start <- unlist(start)
```

You could do it the old nasty way. This may be slow for larger vectors.

```
start <- c()
for (i in 1:n) {
  add <- sample(10)
  start <- c(start, add)
}
```

Comment: *Don't* **ever** do it this way (the latter way). R doesn't grow vectors geometrically like Python when it runs out of room, so running out of space means (1) reallocation of a vector n+1 elements long, (2) n copy operations, and then (3) it will do this *every* iteration. Always pre-allocate.

Comment: Agree with Vince. You said yourself to preallocate a list. You should do exactly the same with a vector.

Comment: I'm just putting out all the options I know. The latter way works for small (sometimes testing) scale purposes. If you're doing something large you need to think about this before hand and working with pre-allocated vectors is actually more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- rnorm(100)
for (i in 100) {
   x <- c(x, rnorm(100))
}
```

This link should be useful: http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/ra/

Comment: No: do **not** do it this way: see my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595459/vector-binding-in-r/3595593#3595593

Comment: And don't use Ra to speed up bad code. It's still experimental and it's cleaner to just write it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your simulation function -- call it func -- returns a vector with the same length each time, you can store the results in the columns of a pre-allocated matrix:

```
sim1 <- function(reps, func) {
  first <- func()
  result <- matrix(first, nrow=length(first), ncol=reps)
  for (i in seq.int(from=2, to=reps - 1)) {
    result[, i] <- func()
  }
  return(as.vector(result))
}
```

Or you could express it as follows using replicate:

```
sim2 <- function(reps, func) {
  return(as.vector(replicate(reps, func(), simplify=TRUE)))
}

> sim2(3, function() 1:3)
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```